# Update Magento 2.1.9 to 2.3

Tags: magento-2.1.9, magento2.3

I'm trying to upgrade my magento store(2.1.9 to 2.3) trough ssh using composer but i'm getting this error(multiple times):

> magento/framework 100.1.9 requires zendframework/zend-stdlib ~2.4.6 ->
>   satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.13, 2.4.1
>   0, 2.4.11, 2.4.12, 2.4.6, 2.4.7, 2.4.8, 2.4.9].

what can i do to solve it? :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these instructions:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Comment: Hey @Alleninfante, but isn't Magento Commerce different than the simple magento that i have?

Comment: You need to follow all instructions for Magento Open Source.

Also check PHP versions:

`2.2 => 7.0.13–7.0.x | 7.1.x`
`2.3 => 7.1.3+ | 7.2.x`